# What is the difference between TextVectorization and Tokenizer?

Tags: keras, nlp, tokenization

What is the difference between the `layers.TextVectorization()` and

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

And when to use what ?

Answer (score 5):

Tokenization is the process of splitting a stream of language into individual tokens.

Vectorization is the process of converting string data into a numerical representation.